# Como deixar uma opção como "default" em uma combobox?

Tags: javascript, html, json

tenho uma combobox com diversos "valores". Vou "chumbar" valores, só para exemplo. Combobox:

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li>
      <div>
         <label>Tipo de Nacionalidade</label>
         <select id="comboTipoId" style="max-width: 350px; width: 350px; background-color: #eee; overflow: hidden; max-height: 37px; height: 37px">

         </select>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Function JS que preenche essa combo (aciono essa function no "onload" da página):

```
function preencherCampos() {       

   /* Busca em arquivo o preenchimento do combobox "Tipo Nacionalidade" */
   /* 'Chumbando' JSON... */
   var consultaTipoId = '{ "tab" : "00000007", "descr" : "Tipo da Nacionalidade", "itens" : [{ "seq" : "1", "value" : "NACIONALIDADE - PF", "key" : "1" }, { "seq" : "2", "value" : "RESIDENCIA FISCAL - PF/PJ", "key" : "2" }, { "seq" : "3", "value" : "VISTO DE PERMANENCIA - PF", "key" : "4" }, { "seq" : "4", "value" : "PAIS DE CONSTITUICAO - PJ", "key" : "5" }, { "seq" : "5", "value" : "PAIS DE NASCIMENTO - PF", "key" : "9" }] }';
   var jsonRespostaCTI = JSON.parse( consultaTipoId );
   for(var i = 0; i < jsonRespostaCTI.itens.length; i++) {
      // get reference to select element
      var sel = document.getElementById('comboTipoId');

      // create new option element
      var opt = document.createElement('option');

      // create text node to add to option element (opt)
      opt.appendChild( document.createTextNode(jsonRespostaCTI.itens[i].value) );

      // set value property of opt
      opt.value = jsonRespostaCTI.itens[i].key;

      // add opt to end of select box (sel)
      sel.appendChild(opt);
   }
   ordenarTpNac();
}
```

Function JS para ordenar a combo em ordem alfabética:

```
function ordenarTpNac() {
   var itensOrdenados = $('#comboTipoId option').sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1;
   });

   $('#comboTipoId').html(itensOrdenados);
}
```

O problema é que, após a ordenação, o valor "default" que aparece pro usuário é "VISTO DE PERMANENCIA - PF" (o último valor). Eu queria que ficasse como "default" o "PAIS DE NASCIMENTO - PF" (chave "9"). Como fazer isso? Tentei colocar algo do tipo if(opt.value === "9") {
                        opt.setected = "selected";
                    } dentro do for da função preencherCampos() mas não deu certo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de fazer o append das options, coloque um `if` para inserir o atributo `selected` na option cujo valor seja `9`:

```
if(jsonRespostaCTI.itens[i].key == 9) opt.setAttribute("selected", "");
```

Irá resultar no HTML:

```
<option value="9" selected>PAIS DE NASCIMENTO - PF</option>
```

Veja:

```js
function preencherCampos() {       

   /* Busca em arquivo o preenchimento do combobox "Tipo Nacionalidade" */
   /* 'Chumbando' JSON... */
   var consultaTipoId = '{ "tab" : "00000007", "descr" : "Tipo da Nacionalidade", "itens" : [{ "seq" : "1", "value" : "NACIONALIDADE - PF", "key" : "1" }, { "seq" : "2", "value" : "RESIDENCIA FISCAL - PF/PJ", "key" : "2" }, { "seq" : "3", "value" : "VISTO DE PERMANENCIA - PF", "key" : "4" }, { "seq" : "4", "value" : "PAIS DE CONSTITUICAO - PJ", "key" : "5" }, { "seq" : "5", "value" : "PAIS DE NASCIMENTO - PF", "key" : "9" }] }';
   var jsonRespostaCTI = JSON.parse( consultaTipoId );
   for(var i = 0; i < jsonRespostaCTI.itens.length; i++) {
      // get reference to select element
      var sel = document.getElementById('comboTipoId');

      // create new option element
      var opt = document.createElement('option');

      // create text node to add to option element (opt)
      opt.appendChild( document.createTextNode(jsonRespostaCTI.itens[i].value) );

      // set value property of opt
      opt.value = jsonRespostaCTI.itens[i].key;
      
      if(jsonRespostaCTI.itens[i].key == 9) opt.setAttribute("selected", "");

      // add opt to end of select box (sel)
      sel.appendChild(opt);
   }
   ordenarTpNac();
}

function ordenarTpNac() {
   var itensOrdenados = $('#comboTipoId option').sort(function (a, b) {
      return a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1;
   });

   $('#comboTipoId').html(itensOrdenados);
}
preencherCampos()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
   <li>
      <div>
         <label>Tipo de Nacionalidade</label>
         <select id="comboTipoId" style="max-width: 350px; width: 350px; background-color: #eee; overflow: hidden; max-height: 37px; height: 37px">

         </select>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: então, cara, o problema dessa solução é que, depois que acaba o for da função preencherCampos(), a função ordenarTpNac() executada em seguida "bagunça" a escolha do default. Eu vi que no seu exemplo, você chamou a função preencherCampos() embaixo da ordenarTpNac() e, por algum motivo que eu não entendi, funcionou no seu exemplo, mas comigo, a página quebrou porque ficou em laço infinito. Não tem como eu escolher o default dentro da função de ordenação (que é executada "por último")?

Comment: Veja, o fato de fazer uma ordenação não muda o option que está selecionado, ele vai continuar selecionado.

Comment: Você está certo, cara, é que eu estava tentando implementar essa mesma alteração numa outra combobox e não deu certo. Acho que é porque o JSON é diferente, e aí, eu tenho que alterar algo na lógica; você pode me ajudar a enxergar o que é?

Comment: vou postar num novo comentário, senão, excede o limite de caracteres... Hehe

Comment: var novoJSON = '{ "tab" : "00000004", "descr" : "Pais", "itens" : [ { "seq" : "45", "value" : "BOTSWANA", "key" : "045", "ufs" : [] }, { "seq" : "46", "value" : "BRASIL", "key" : "046", "ufs" : [ { "seq" : "1", "value" : "RONDONIA", "abrev" : "RO", "key" : "000010", "doc" : [ { "seq" : "1", "value" : "REGISTRO GERAL SEM CPF", "key" : "00007", "emissao" : "S", "venc" : "N", "exp" : [ { "seq" : "1", "value" : "DIRETORIA IDENTIFICAÇÃO CIVIL", "key" : "DIC " } ] } ], "municipios" : [ { "seq" : "1", "value" : "ARIQUEMES", "key" : "0000009393" } ] } ] } ] }';

Comment: esse novoJSON, quando eu parseio e percorro ele, mesmo botando o if que você colocou, não funciona (queria que o Brasil ficasse visível pro usuário, chave "046"). O país fica selecionado na aplicação (já fiz o teste), mas o que aparece para o usuário é o último país ordenado do JSON (o último item do "colchete" "itens"). Lembrando que coloquei só parte desse novo JSON aqui (o mínimo para ficar "inteligível", pelo menos), porque ele é muito grande... Tem todos os países do mundo, mais os estados e municípios do Brasil, com órgãos emissores de documentos, ficaria inviável postar o JSON inteiro.

Comment: Esses JSON's vc tá puxando como? É no PHP, AJAX? Acho que há uma forma melhor de escolher o option padrão.

Comment: Então, eu puxo por uma função. Essa função está num aplicativo Android. É que eu, na verdade, tô fazendo só o front desse aplicativo Android. Aí, uma das exigências é essa: deixar o país Brasil como "default" pro usuário pra facilitar o preenchimento do formulário.

Comment: Acho que seria melhor, após popular o select, fazer: `$("#comboTipoId option[value='9']").attr("selected", "");`

Comment: puxa, cara, assim funcionou, joguei esse trecho de código na função que ordena, logo após ela terminar de ordenar e funcionou!!! :) brigadão!